# How to get data from other website to my website using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I want get data from this website: https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/pubfunc?ID=EnquireTransferFee

This is my code using CURL:

```
function postPage($url, $pvars, $referer, $timeout){
    if(!isset($timeout))
        $timeout=30;
    $curl = curl_init();
    $post = http_build_query($pvars);
    if(isset($referer)){
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    }
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    $html = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    return $html;
}
$vars = array(
    'vehicleNo'    => 'SFT4228H',
    'transferDate' => '10042014'
);

$result = postPage('test.php', $vars, 'https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/pubfunc?ID=EnquireTransferFee', '30');

print "Result:".$result; //Show data in my website
```

=> How to get this data

Answer (score 0):

As you have it here, it appears that you are using curl to request "test.php".

Try switching them around in your function call:

```
$result = postPage('https://vrl.lta.gov.sg/lta/vrl/action/pubfunc?ID=EnquireTransferFee', $vars, 'test.php', '30');
```

Comment: When I post the data in $vars to this page using a regular old HTML form, I see a page with the form on it.  The URL you're trying to post data to doesn't do anything with the data.  What are you trying to accomplish here?